# A verb to show dependency between two people

Tags: word-choice

How can I say that 2 people are dependent each other in a formal letter.

Is it ok to say that :

> My father has been living with my mother for more than 30 years and they are dependent to each other emotionally.

Comment: Since the second phrase is a conclusion, you might also write "...for more than 30 years, *so/therefore* they are dependent..."

Comment: Cleaner to say "... they depend on each other ..."

Answer (score 1):

You have no problem with your verb; however, we typically use the preposition *on* in this case, not *to*:

> They are dependent **on** each other emotionally.

As a footnote, the [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dependent+on+each+other%2C+dependent+to+each+other&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) shows this to be the case.

Comment: "You have no problem with your **verb**". Is **verb** you meant to say?

Comment: @JavaLatte - The verb is *are*; that seems like the right verb to use in this case. (I mentioned "verb" because of the title of the question).

Answer (score 0):

You could put it in the following ways:

> they are emotionally attached

### OR

> they are emotionally connected

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for is **codependent**. If two people depend on each other, they are codependent. However, this word has a negative connotation in many contexts because emotional codependency is seen as unhealthy in relationships. It is even used sometimes as a kind of "diagnosis" of problems in a relationship.